# Redirect to a particular child state whenever a particular parent state is found in Angular UI

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

I want to redirect from a parent state to a particular child state all the time. Please refer below :

```
$stateProvider.state('dashboard.view-bills', {
    url: '/individual/view-bills',
    templateUrl: 'modules/view-bill-module/partial/current-invoices/current-invoices.html',
    ncyBreadcrumb: {
        label: ' View Bills'
      }
});

$stateProvider.state('dashboard.view-bills.current-invoices', {
    url: '/current-invoices',
    templateUrl: 'modules/view-bill-module/partial/current-invoices/current-invoices.html',
    ncyBreadcrumb: {
        label: ' Current Invoices'
      }
});

$stateProvider.state('dashboard.view-bills.history-invoices', {
    url: '/invoices',
    templateUrl: 'modules/view-bill-module/partial/history-invoices/history-invoices.html',
    ncyBreadcrumb: {
        label: ' Invoice History'
      }
});
```

Here, I want to go the 'dashboard.view-bills.current-invoices' state whenever I am in `dashboard.view-bills` state. I am using [angular-breadcrumb](https://github.com/ncuillery/angular-breadcrumb) from breadcrumbs.

I have used the following code to change the URL :
`$urlRouterProvider.when('/individual/view-bills' , '/individual/view-bills/current-invoices');`

But with this code, the state doesn't change, What is the best way of doing this ? And also, is there any function like : `$stateRouterProvider.when('matcher-state' , 'destination-state');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep the line `$urlRouterProvider.when('/individual/view-bills' , '/individual/view-bills/current-invoices')`, you have done half of the job.

What are you missing is the `abstract: true` in state `dashboard.view-bills` to make the state change.

Source : https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-set-up-a-defaultindex-child-state

Thanks for using angular-breadcrumb, btw ;)

Comment: angular-breadcrumb did made my life very easy. 
But I have already tried making the state 'abstract:true' , but in that case , the label in the abstract state is not visible, and thus I am unable to have all the proper labels in the breadcrumb. I hope I am able to explain the problem. :)

Comment: I added the feature you need few weeks ago : See the global option `includeAbstract` @ https://github.com/ncuillery/angular-breadcrumb/wiki/API-Reference#options

Comment: Awesome :) I shall try that :)